# Is this table accessibility safe

Tags: html, accessibility

I have to show a html table and it has to be accessibility safe. I have added th with scope ="col" and header and ids. Please tell me what necessary changes to do to make it correct.

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table caption="Products Table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="prodname" scope="col" style="font-size: 14px;">Product Name </th>
      <th id="orderdate" scope="col" style="font-size: 14px;;">Order Date</th>
      <th id="type" scope="col" style="font-size: 14px;">Type</th>
      <th id="storelocation" scope="col" style="font-size: 14px;">Store Location</th>
      <th id="brand" scope="col" style="font-size:14px;">Brand</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="Brush" scope="row" style="text-align:left; font-size: 14px;;">Brush</th>
      <td style="text-align:left">1/1/19</td>
      <td style="text-align:left">Online</td>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>Brand1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <th colspan="5" headers="City Brush" scope="row"> <b>California: </b> <span style="font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;;"> City1, City2, City 3, City 4</span> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <th colspan="5" headers="City Brush" scope="row"> <b>NewYork: </span> <span style="font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;;"> City5, City6, City 7, City 8</span> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <th colspan="5" headers="City Brush" scope="row"> <b>New Jersey: </span> <span style="font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;;"> City1, City9, City 10, City 12</span> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="book" scope="row" style="text-align:left; font-size: 14px;;">Book</th>
                <td style="text-align:left">1/2/19</td>
                <td style="text-align:left">In-Store</td>
                <td>002</td>
                <td>Brand2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <th colspan="5" headers="City Brush" scope="row"> <span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;;">California: </span> <span style="font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;;"> City1, City2, City 3, City 4</span> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <th colspan="5" headers="City Brush" scope="row"> <b>NewYork: </span> <span style="font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;;"> City5, City6, City 7, City 8</span> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <th colspan="5" headers="City Brush" scope="row"> <b> New Jersey: </span> <span style="font-weight: normal;font-size: 14px;;"> City1, City9, City 10, City 12</span> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am trying to show a product table with the product name, order date, type (purchased online or instore), store location, brand name. I also want to show in each state, how many stores has this product(show comma separated city names).

I tried to show a new row with colspan =5 and display the state name and cities name next to each other.

I want to make sure the table structure passes the accessibility standards.

Comment: Instead of `caption="Products Table"` (which AFAIK doesn't exist) -- use `<caption>Products Table</caption>` before `<thead>`.

Comment: Try asking here at Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

For more accessibility i won't use a table as shown here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp (yellow's background note)
In your case datas are tabular so it could fit to a table but you've to avoid  element such 'b' who has no semantic(description) value and set a table of Content to each tabular datas who're composite in each cell of the tables using section ->article-> header.(although using that would make the HTML table useless once you've set CSS for element layout in page as row and columns+i think-but not sure- table content not referenced as well as not table one's).

See also data type for more precise definition of setting datas types in HTML.
like this one but you've more specifics way to do it like using predefined data type(like for date information) as well as personnal datas definition:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

more infos here about general accessibilities rules  https://www.w3.org/WAI/

I've found that tools too(searching for a table of content validator i've not found):
https://wet-boew.github.io/v4.0-ci/demos/tablevalidator/tablevalidator-en.html